# Consuming web API into Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to consume a web API into Blazor but am struggling to extract certain information from the API

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace CA3.Song
{
    public class SongService : ISongService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        const string _baseUrl = "https://genius-song-lyrics1.p.rapidapi.com/";
        const string _songEndpoint = "songs/chart?time_period=day&chart_genre=all&per_page=10&page=1";
        const string _host = "genius-song-lyrics1.p.rapidapi.com";
        const string _key = "{key}";

        public SongService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<List<SongItem>> GetSong()
        {
            Configure();

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_songEndpoint);
            var response_outcome = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode;

            using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var dto = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<SongDto>(stream);
            return dto.response.chart_items.Select(n => new SongItem { Artist = n.item.primary_artist, Title = n.item.primary_title, ReleaseDate = n.primary_release_date }).ToList().T ;
        }

        private void Configure()
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RapidAPI-Host", _host);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Rapid-Key", _key);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is on the return statement using LINQ.

```
namespace CA3.Song
{
    public class SongDto
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public Chart_Items[] chart_items { get; set; }
        public int next_page { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chart_Items
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public int annotation_count { get; set; }
        public string api_path { get; set; }
        public string artist_names { get; set; }
        public string full_title { get; set; }
        public string header_image_thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string header_image_url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool instrumental { get; set; }
        public int lyrics_owner_id { get; set; }
        public string lyrics_state { get; set; }
        public int lyrics_updated_at { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public int pyongs_count { get; set; }
        public string relationships_index_url { get; set; }
        public Release_Date_Components release_date_components { get; set; }
        public string release_date_for_display { get; set; }
        public string song_art_image_thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string song_art_image_url { get; set; }
        public Stats stats { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string title_with_featured { get; set; }
        public int updated_by_human_at { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Featured_Artists[] featured_artists { get; set; }
        public Primary_Artist primary_artist { get; set; }
    }

    public class Release_Date_Components
    {
        public int year { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stats
    {
        public int unreviewed_annotations { get; set; }
        public int concurrents { get; set; }
        public bool hot { get; set; }
        public int pageviews { get; set; }
    }

    public class Primary_Artist
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string api_path { get; set; }
        public string header_image_url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public string index_character { get; set; }
        public bool is_meme_verified { get; set; }
        public bool is_verified { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int iq { get; set; }
    }

    public class Featured_Artists
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string api_path { get; set; }
        public string header_image_url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public string index_character { get; set; }
        public bool is_meme_verified { get; set; }
        public bool is_verified { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int iq { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Above is the JSON file and I'm trying to extract the artist name, song title and release date from Item but it isn't in a list so I'm trying to find a way to extract this info using LINQ. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Is this in your actual code on the return ....ToList().T ; ?  If it is remove the .T part.  If that isn't part of the actual code then what is your issue on the return?  Using debug should help you see what the issue is.

Comment: You should provide a sample JSON for better clarity. Many times these issues arise from a faulty hierarchy of objects, causing it not to line up exactly with the json structure. Also keep in mind that for your DTO class, you only need to specify the json fields you want from it as properties. If you know for a fact you don't need a field, just omit it from the class, and it won't get deserialized. This should help you focus in on getting and processing the data you want out of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted the declaration of the JSON. They are stored in an array `Chart_Items[] chart_items` thus you may use linq.

There are many ways to do this, I took advantage of named tuples in modern C# paired with linq.

```
Response r = new Response();//some resonse from api
var results = r.chart_items.Select(i => (i.item.artist_names, i.item.title, i.item.release_date_components)).ToList();

foreach(var result in results)
{
    string artist_names = result.artist_names;
    string title = result.title;
    Release_Date_Components release_date_components = result.release_date_components;
}
```